# Error in performing bit-wise OR and 32 bit sign bit extension in Java

Tags: java, binary, bitwise-operators

I'm having trouble understanding bit-wise OR in java. I'm reading a Java programming book named "Apress Beginning Java7" by  Jeff Friesen.

And in that book at page-31 the author gave two 8 bit binary numbers and performed bit-wise OR on those two numbers. He said that:

> 0B0001 1010 | 0B1011 0111 results in 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
>   1011 1111

Then he said that and I quote:

*"The &, ^, and | operators in the last three lines first convert their byte integer operands to 32-bit
integer values (through sign bit extension, copying the sign bit’s value into the extra bits) before
performing their operations."*

Now if I understand correctly the first 8 bit number(`0B0001 1010`) by sign bit extension becomes(32bit number):

> `0B0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0001 1010`

And the second number (`0B1011 0111`) by sign bit extension becomes:

> `0B1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1011 0111`

If I bit-wise OR these two extended numbers I get:

> `0B1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1011 1111`

But the author got:

> `0B0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 1011 1111`

Can anyone tell where I am wrong on this? I mean can anyone kindly tell me why my answer is different from author's and
where I made the mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`0B10110111` binary literal has a value of type `int`. It is not implicitly promoted from `byte`, so there is no sign extension.

If it was `(byte)0B10110111` then you would have what you expect.